# when I symmetrize armature it won't mirror the y axis 3.5

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, mirror, parent

I am trying to symmetrize this armature in blender 3.5 so that it is mirrored across the y axis. it is on the x axis right now. when I use symmetrize it gives me a rotated version intersecting the current .l version, but i want it mirrored across the y axis.

I have tried switching what axis it is on, moving that orange dot, parenting it to a main head, and also mirroring it along the x and/or y axis, but still it is not a perfect mirror. How do I make it mirror like I see in tutorials when they click symmetrize and it's mirrored right away?

[image: once I click symmetrize I get this]

Comment: Is your armature object rotated 90 degrees?

Comment: yeah i did that when i started so now it is along the x axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object's rotation doesn't impact its content rotation. Your bones may look like they are on the X axis thanks to your armature object's rotation, but in local space they are still on Y axis.

Either apply your armature object's rotation using <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Apply Scale in object mode, or remove your armature object's rotation by hitting <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> in object mode, and reposition your bones in edit mode instead.